# How to use an Intent in MenuItems to open a new fragment in android?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-viewpager, slideshow, menuitem

I am using viewPager in my slide show,it has got 3 menu items namely action_previous,action_next and action_finish......[image: these menuitems are at the bottom and when the slide show starts then]
previous and next menu item is seen then [image: when we click these and when we reach at the end of the slideshow of the viewpager,we get like this:]

So my question here is how to go to an another fragment from this menu item>"Finish" using intent???
my codes for the slide show for menu are as follows:

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_tutorial, menu);



    menu.findItem(R.id.action_previous).setEnabled(mPager.getCurrentItem() > 0);

    // Add either a "next" or "finish" button to the action bar, depending on which page
    // is currently selected.
    MenuItem item = menu.add(Menu.NONE, R.id.action_next, Menu.NONE,
            (mPager.getCurrentItem() == mPagerAdapter.getCount() - 1)
                    ? R.string.action_finish
                    : R.string.action_next);
    item.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_WITH_TEXT);

    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            // Navigate "up" the demo structure to the launchpad activity.
            // See http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html for more.
            NavUtils.navigateUpTo(this, new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
            return true;

        case R.id.action_previous:
            // Go to the previous step in the wizard. If there is no previous step,
            // setCurrentItem will do nothing.
            mPager.setCurrentItem(mPager.getCurrentItem() - 1);
            return true;


        case R.id.action_next:


            // Advance to the next step in the wizard. If there is no next step, setCurrentItem
            // will do nothing.
            mPager.setCurrentItem(mPager.getCurrentItem() + 1);
            return true;
}

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this inside your onOptionsItemSelected

```
case R.id.action_finish:
startActivity(new Intent(this,NewActivity.class));
return true;
```